# Info Shows in Console but not in HTML

Tags: javascript, json

Good evening,

I've been fighting with this for 2 days. Please help!! I'm still learning, and I've gotten to JSON objects and AJAX. I've managed to get the names to show up in the console. However, it doesn't show up in the div. Should I be using appendChild() in order to inject it into the DOM?

Simple JSON:

```
{
  "Instructors" : [

  {
  "full_name" : "Ray Villalobos",
  "title" : "Staff Author",
  "links" : [
        { "blog"     : "http://iviewsource.com" },
        { "facebook" : "http://facebook.com/iviewsource" },
        { "podcast"  : "http://feeds.feedburner.com/authoredcontent" },
        { "twitter"  : "http://twitter.com/planetoftheweb" },
        { "youtube"  : "http://www.youtube.com/planetoftheweb" }
    ]
   },

   {
     "full_name" : "Quincy Adams",
     "title" : "Mega Author",
     "links" : [
        { "blog"     : "http://getoffmytip.com" },
        { "facebook" : "http://facebook.com/getoffmytip" },
        { "podcast"  : "http://feeds.feedburner.com/getoffmytip" },
        { "twitter"  : "http://twitter.com/surpassedgoddess" },
        { "youtube"  : "http://www.youtube.com/surpassedgoddess" }
        ]
    }
       ]
    }
```

Script.js:

```
$(function() {
function getData() {

var request;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    request=new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    request=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

request.open('GET', 'data.json');
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if ((request.status === 200) &&
        (request.readyState === 4)) {

        var info = JSON.parse(request.responseText); 

        var author = '';
        for (var i = 0; i <= info.Instructors.length-1; i++) {
            for (key in info.Instructors[i]) {
                if (info.Instructors[i].hasOwnProperty(key)) {

        }//for hasOwnProperty

            }//for each object
            author += '<p>' + info.Instructors[i].full_name + '</p>';
        }//for each array element
        document.getElementsByClassName('div1').innerHTML = author;
        console.log(author);
} //ready
} //event
request.send();
}//getData  
window.addEventListener("load", getData);

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there problem is here`document.getElementsByClassName('div1')`.

`document.getElementsByClassName('div1')` gives you the list of all the divs with the class name you mentioned. If there is just one div it is still gonna return you a list with that node in it. What you should do is access that node with `document.getElementsByClassName('div1')[0]` (if you want to append it the first div or there is only one div with class `div1`).

ps. You don't want to scan all the DOM again and again to find that node, so you better get that reference outside of your for loop and then append `html` or whatever you want.

**NOTE**

You should use `document.querySelector('selector')` coz it is relatively more powerful and useful when you have complex selectors.

ps.  `querySelectorAll` and `getElementsByClassName`: the return value is different. `querySelectorAll` will return a static collection, while `getElementsByClassName` returns a live collection.

Comment: That's exactly what my problem was. Sorry for the late response.